# List of people who have done one thing and gotten nice rep for it

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I was playing with StackQL and asked myself. Are there people who have as much rep as their highest voted question/answer (as in, they've only gotten rep from that one question/answer).

The query isn't that complicated but you have to filter out the people who have answered one question, gotten 1 upvote and have 10 rep. Since thats no fun. So I limited it to >= 100 rep.

```
SELECT Posts.Id, Posts.Score, Users.Id, Users.Reputation FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId 
WHERE (Posts.Score * 10) = Users.Reputation AND Users.Reputation >= 100 
ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC
```

These are the questions / answers.

- [Answer to - Boxing when using generics in C# (230 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646517/boxing-when-using-generics-in-c/646584#646584)
- [Question - Why would I want to use Interfaces? (220 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240152)
- [Question - What is the difference between an asp.net web method and a wcf service? (180 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216931)
- [Answer to - Can an element’s CSS class be set via JavaScript? (160 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110354/can-an-elements-css-class-be-set-via-javascript/110361#110361)
- [Answer to - Best Java book you have read so far (150 rep) (this might be a fluke though)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75102/best-java-book-you-have-read-so-far/75138#75138)
- [Question - Computer science final year project ideas (150 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892731)
- [Question - Determining if ASP.Net is properly registered (150 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078197)
- [Question - How relevant is Win32 programming to modern professionals? (110 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506396)
- [Question - What would be a good sample project to ask a prospective programmer to code during the hiring process? (110 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047232)

The questions are often interesting but generic but it's the answers that intrigue me. For example the top one. [That user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63787/ruiyiz) has not done anything but voted a few times and answered that one answer.

The fluke one might be because of CW not being enabled at the start of his answers. He has two, both CW answers.

The third answer is similar to the first one, although [he has answered two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19861/jonah) but the other answer has 0 votes.

Even though the list isn't that exciting, it's still a bit interesting.

**UPDATE:**

I did a query with +100. I was worried that there would be to many cases where people had gotten upvotes from other places.

```
SELECT Posts.Id, Posts.Score, Users.Id, Users.Reputation FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId
WHERE (Posts.Score * 10) + 100 = Users.Reputation AND Users.Reputation >= 200
ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC
```

I did >= 200 because otherwise I got pages and pages of results. This is the breakdown of the query.

- [Tim (309 rep).](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60469/tim) Got 210 from one question. Two account associations with SO. But no rep on SO from that.
- [giltotherescue (270 rep).](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8215). Rep from other questions. No assoc.
- [Mohit Ranka (240 rep).](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22956) Most from one of his 28 questions. Matched query because he has one CW question with 14 votes. No assoc
- [rofly (230 rep).](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14877) Similar situation as Mohit. No assoc
- [qrunchmonkey (210 rep).](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81720) Rep from other stuff. No assoc.
- [Daz (200 rep).](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85662) Rep from other stuff. No assoc.

So account association has no effect here, we just get bad results.

**UPDATE 2**

Looks like I had forgotten the initial 1 rep. So I have fixed the query (I'll leave the original stuff intact) But what happened to the starting 1 rep is a good question.

So here is the same list but with a fixed query.

```
SELECT Posts.Id, Posts.Score, Users.Id, Users.Reputation FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Users ON Users.Id = Posts.OwnerUserId
WHERE (Posts.Score * 10) + 1 = Users.Reputation AND Users.Reputation >= 300
ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC
```

I limited this one to >= 300 since the list was pretty long.

- [Scott Stanchfield (441 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12432/scott-stanchfield)
- [Jay Kimble (411 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32073)
- [Hamster (331 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47501)
- [Long Time Smalltalker (321 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86492)
- [Mark (311 rep)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25340) (This one has more answers and rep for that)

Comment: Don't forget to adjust for the +100 bonus for associating accounts.

Comment: How would I proceed in doing that? Since association isn't in the datadump and I can't do +100 since people could have gotten 10 upvotes somewhere else.

Comment: perhaps instead of `where (Posts.Score * 10) = Users.Reputation`, OR that with `(Posts.Score * 10) + 100 = Users.Reputation`? It seems odd that the +100 isn't in the DB anywhere: does this mean it would disappear with a rep recalc?

Comment: What's happened to the initial reputation of 1 in all of this?

Comment: Hmm good question. I'll run the query with rep +1. See if i get anything more.

Comment: Interestingly, Scott Stanchfield also has a registered account with 2.4k rep (http://stackoverflow.com/users/12541/scott-stanchfield). Those accounts really should be merged.

Comment: As (nameless) others would say "What's the question?". But seriously, this is interesting stuff. I can't help wondering what happened to http://stackoverflow.com/users/63787/ruiyiz though. He/she joined 8 months ago, had brilliant success with the first answer, but hasn't been seen since August 27.

Comment: @pavium maybe you can ask him: http://twitter.com/ruiyiz since his webpage doesn't offer much info other than his name (Ruiyi Zhang). He seems to also use linkedIn: http://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/Ruiyi/Zhang/