# What was the question or answer in SO that gave the highest number of reputation points to one user?

Tags: discussion, reputation

The FAQ says that an user can earn at most 200 of reputation points per day. But since some questions keep being viewed, answered, voted for many days, one can theoretically earn more than 200 points with one question.

Does anybody know what SO question or answer gave the highest number of reputation points to an user?

Comment: Related to this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26502/list-of-people-who-have-done-one-thing-and-gotten-nice-rep-for-it ?

Comment: dupe?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites/11022#11022

Comment: I guess that answer didn't link to highest rep answer though, just every other form of highest.

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891643) gave [Brian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69755/brian-campbell) a total of [886 Rep points](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69755?tab=reputationhistory#sort-top) from upvotes (which you can see if you highlight the entire steeply rising portion of his Rep graph). He also got two down votes and subsequently burned 500 of the Rep points on a bounty for that question.